are questions regarding buy and sell bitcoin operators acceptable?
I am having a hard time finding information regarding market operators of bitcoin that operate near where i live (Panama), i've seen lot of confusing information on the internet and is hard to know how trustable are most operators found on the internet. 
In any case, i was hoping to ask about this in the forum but i'm not sure if it fits in the site guidelines, as i've seen most of the questions are regarding the bitcoin technology, rather than the actual market.

Such a question would probably get closed as "too localized" or as a dupe of this question. It's not necessarily that this site is for the technology rather than the market, it's that questions about the market tend to be a poor fit for the StackExchange format.
StackExchange questions should have lasting value, and questions which are very geographically or temporally constrained typically have no value for anyone but the asker or have value that fades almost immediately - definitely not what SE is hoping to achieve. In all honsty IRC or the forums might be a better resource for this particular question.
We definitely do appreciate your asking, however! Life as a moderator would be much easier if we had more users who asked good questions on meta before just posting on the main site.
